# Blocking an incomming foreign address with fail2ban or iptables

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, iptables, fail2ban

I am trying to ban an "IP address" or hostname dont know what this is : static.40.25.69.1 from my ubuntu droplet but without any luck. Banning ip addresses was easy but i cant manage to do anything with the given address. The given address is crawling the site and adding a big load on the server so i need to block them somehow.

My question is how can i block them with iptables/fail2ban?

For ip addresses i had a manban jail and i added them there but the given address is not recognized as a valid ipaddress so nothing happens.

I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Netstat is showing the following:

```
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:34918 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:44008 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:48032 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:59180 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:55064 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:35442 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:50676 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:59708 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:43686 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:44120 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:43996 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:38754 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       1      0 ingatlanmaps.hu:https   static.40.25.69.1:35100 CLOSE_WAIT
```

Many thanks,
Trix

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find an answer. To find out the IP address that you need to ban you need to add an additional paramater to netstat so you can get the numerical ip address.

netstat -n is the command needed.